# Using xor operator in enhanced for loop in Java

Tags: java, xor

sorry if this is a duplicate but I tried my hardest and couldn't find what exactly I'm doing wrong. I'm working on java concepts in hopes to take the certification exam in the upcoming year, and I'm playing around with enhanced for loops and getting used to using them. I tried making an enhanced for loop to search through an array, and using the xor (^) operator I'm wanting to determine the location of an element that matches another variable. the code I currently have is:

```
int[] x = {17, 16, 15};
    int y = 16;
    int z;
    for (int a : x) {
        z = x[a]^16;

        if (z==0)
            System.out.println(a);
        else;
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting an error. I know it has to do with the way I'm accessing the array at (z=x[a]^16), is there a better way to write this that I'm just not seeing? Thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: Hint: reading the error message helps a lot. Second hint: naming variables correctly helps a lot too. Rename `x` to `array`, and `a` to `element`, and you should figure it out.

Comment: `z = x[a]^16;` should be `z = a^16;`

Comment: Surely `z = x[a]^16; if (z == 0)` is just a convoluted way to write `if (x[a] == 16)`. Why do you need the xor operator?

Comment: `else;`? Well, *that's* useless. Hint: always use braces with `if` statements, it'll save you a world of hurt in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, and to clarify on why I was using the ^ instead of x[a]=16, the point of this was to figure out how to use an enhanced for loop with the xor operator. I just wanted to test my knowledge on different things stacking up to see where my flaws are. thanks again though for all the advice and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enhanced for loop provides each element in the array or list, not the index to the element. So, the first time around, a = 17. x[17] should give an array index exception. Note that your code compiles only because you created an array of int; if it was an array of String, then you would end up with a compile error.

In the future, include the error messages you get when you run your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't understanding the fact that "a" was already providing the element and not the index, that was a huge headache for me. I was assuming that since it was an enhanced for loop the variable "a" was correlating to the length of the array. And sorry for not including the error message, I'll definitely remember to do that in the future!